# Uploading a file and submitting a form at the same time, using vb

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net, forms

so I have a slight issue with doing 2 things on a web page. I'm using a  to upload a file to my web server, at the same time I have other  used to get data from the user (first name, last name ect) The form is runat=server, the button that is supposed to upload the file (after some preliminary checking that the file is ok, and that the forms fields are filled out properly) is also runat server, with a onserver click.

The main issue is that, when I give the form a "get" method, I can get the desired result of having all my data in the url where I want it, but then I can't upload a file. While if I remove that tag, I can upload a file, but then I get no data in my url.

(Relevant code)

```
    <script language="VB" runat="server">
        Dim str As String
        Sub Button1_Click(ByVal Source As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

            'Dim submitFunction As String = "<script type='text/javascript'> function submitform() { document.myform.submit();}" & "</" & "script>"
            Session("firstTime") = 4
            Session("errCheck") = 1
            If InputF.Value = "" Then
                Span1.InnerHtml = "Error: you must enter a file name"
                Return
            End If

            If Not (InputF.PostedFile Is Nothing) Then
                Try
                    If Session("firstTime") <> 1 Then

                        If Request.QueryString("fName") = "" Then
                            str += "Please Enter your first name <br/>"
                            Session("errCheck") += 1
                        End If
                        If Request.QueryString("lName") = "" Then
                            str += "Please Enter your last name <br />"
                            Session("errCheck") += 1
                        End If
                        If Request.QueryString("addr1") = "" Then
                            str += "Please Enter your address <br />"
                            Session("errCheck") += 1
                        End If
                        If Request.QueryString("city") = "" Then
                            str += "Please Enter a city name <br />"
                            Session("errCheck") += 1
                        End If
                        If Len(Request.QueryString("prov")) <> 2 Then
                            str += "Please Enter a 2 character province <br />"
                            Session("errCheck") += 1
                        End If
                        If Len(Request.QueryString("pCode")) <> 6 Then
                            str += "Please Enter a valid postal code <br />"
                            Session("errCheck") += 1
                        End If
                        If Request.QueryString("hPhone") = "" Then
                            str += "Please Enter your home phone <br />"
                            Session("errCheck") += 1
                        ElseIf Len(Request.QueryString("hPhone")) <> 10 Then
                            str += "Please enter a 10 digit number for your home phone <br />"
                            Session("errCheck") += 1
                        End If
                    End If
                    If Session("errCheck") = 1 Then
                        InputF.PostedFile.SaveAs(("FILE PATH TO MY SERVER" & Request.QueryString("compName") & " - " & Request.QueryString("fName") & ", " & Request.QueryString("lName") & InputF.Value))
                        'Response.Redirect("default.aspx?fName=" & Request.QueryString("fName"))
                    End If

                Catch exc As Exception
                    str += "Error Saving File"
                    Span1.InnerHtml = "Error saving file"
                    Session("errCheck") += 1
                End Try

            End If

        End Sub 'Button1_Click 

</script>


                    <form  name="myform" id="myform" method="get" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <table>
                        <h2><%  If Session("errCheck") <> 1 Then
                                    Response.Write(Str)
                                End If%></h2>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right"><label>Resume/Documents</label></td>
                            <td><input type="file" runat="server" id="InputF" name="InputF" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)" /><input type="button" id="adder" value="add another document" onclick="addInput('dynamicInput');" /></td>
                            <div id="dynamicInput">
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>                
                                <span id=Span1 
                                style="font: 8pt verdana;" 
                                runat="server" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <input type="hidden" id="Hidden13" name="compName" value="<% response.Write(request.QueryString("compName")) %>" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="posCode" name="posCode" value="<% response.Write(request.QueryString("posCode"))%>" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="reqNum" name="reqNum" value="<% response.Write(request.QueryString("reqNum")) %>" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="company" name="company" value="<% response.Write(request.QueryString("company"))%>" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="division" name="division" value="<% response.Write(request.QueryString("division")) %>" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="department" name="department" value="<% response.Write(request.QueryString("department"))%>" />
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">First name<span style="color:Red;">*</span>:</td>
                            <td><input type='text' name='fName' id='fName'  size='50'  maxlength="50"value="<% Response.Write(Request.QueryString("fName"))%>" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right"><label>Last name </label><span style="color:Red;">*</span>:</td>
                            <td><input type='text' name='lName' id='lName'  size='50'  maxlength="50" value="<% response.Write(request.QueryString("lName"))%>"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right"><label>Initial</label>:</td>
                            <td><input type='text' name='init' id='init'  size='2'  maxlength="2" value="<% response.Write(request.QueryString("init"))%>"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right"><label>Email</label>:</td>
                            <td><input type='text' name='email' id='email'  size='50' maxlength="50" value="<% response.Write(request.QueryString("email"))%>"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right"><label>Address 1</label><span style="color:Red;">*</span>:</td>
                            <td><input type='text' name='addr1' id='addr1'  size='25' maxlength="25" value="<% response.Write(request.QueryString("addr1"))%>"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right"><label>Address 2</label>:</td>
                            <td><input type='text' name='addr2' id='addr2'  size='25' maxlength="25" value="<% response.Write(request.QueryString("addr2"))%>"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right"><label>City</label><span style="color:Red;">*</span>:</td>
                            <td><input type='text' name='city' id='city'  size='25' maxlength="25" value="<% response.Write(request.QueryString("city"))%>"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <br />
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right"><label>Province</label><span style="color:Red;">*</span>:</td>
                            <td><input type='text' name='prov' id='prov'  size='2' maxlength="2" value="<% response.Write(request.QueryString("prov"))%>"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right"><label>Country</label>:</td>
                            <td><input type='text' name='count' id='count'  size='25' maxlength="25" value="<% response.Write(request.QueryString("count"))%>"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right"><label>Postal code</label><span style="color:Red;">*</span>:</td>
                            <td><input type='text' name='pCode' id='pCode'  size='25' maxlength="25" value="<% response.Write(request.QueryString("pCode"))%>"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right"><label>Home Phone</label><span style="color:Red;">*</span>:</td>
                            <td><input type='text' name='hPhone' id='hPhone'  size='15' maxlength="15" value="<% response.Write(request.QueryString("hPhone"))%>"/></td>
                            <p>Format for phone numbers: Areacode, phone number, no spaces, no dashes ie: 2041231234</P>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right"><label>Work Phone</label>:</td>
                            <td><input type='text' name='wPhone' id='wPhone'  size='25' maxlength="25" value="<% response.Write(request.QueryString("wPhone"))%>"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                           <input type=button 
                            id="Button1" 
                            value="Submit Application" 
                            OnServerClick="Button1_Click" 
                            runat="server" />
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was close to getting this myself. On form submit, I do all the validation for the other files, then if all checks out, I submit the form to a different page(with other non-relevant code).

Basically the code I posted is good, I was just missing a few things for when it's submitted

In short:

```
'if there are no errors with the user feilds
If Session("errCheck") = 1 Then
                    Try
                    If Not (System.IO.Path.GetFileName(InputF.PostedFile.FileName.ToString()) Is Nothing) Then
                        Try
                            InputF.PostedFile.SaveAs(("somepath:\somepath\somepath\somepath\" & Trim(Request.Form("compName")) & " - " & Request.Form("lName") & ", " & Request.Form("fName") & "-" & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(InputF.PostedFile.FileName.ToString())))
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            Session("errCheck") += 1
                            str += "Error Saving File" & ex.Message
                        End Try
If Session("errCheck") = 1 Then
                        Response.Redirect("final2.aspx?fName=" & Request.Form("fName") & "&lName=" & Request.Form("lName") & "&compName=" & Trim(Request.Form("compName")) &
                        "&posCode=" & Request.Form("posCode") & "&reqNum=" & Request.Form("reqNum") & "&company=" & Request.Form("company") & 
                        "&division=" & Request.Form("division") & "&department=" & Request.Form("department") & "&init=" & Request.Form("init") & 
                        "&email=" & Request.Form("email") & "&addr1=" & Trim(Request.Form("addr1")) & "&addr2=" & Request.Form("addr2") & 
                        "&city=" & Request.Form("city") & "&prov=" & Request.Form("prov") & "&count=" & Request.Form("count") & 
                        "&pCode=" & Request.Form("pCode") & "&hPhone=" & Request.Form("hPhone") & "&wPhone=" & Request.Form("wPhone"))
                    End If
```

Hopefully that makes sense to anyone looking at my question and now my answer.